# How is a short circuit useful at all for measuring the power transmitted through a transformer?

Tags: power, transformer, short-circuit

In the attached figure, "find the complex power transmitted to the load through each transformer." The solution (not shown) states that "with ΔV short-circuited, the current in each path is half the load current..."

If we are asked to measure the power transmitted to the load through each transformer, why do we need to do any short-circuiting whatsoever? Doesn't a short circuit imply that the power does NOT reach the load?

[image]

<sup>Source: *Power Systems Analysis* (Grainger/Stevenson/Chang)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In circuit analysis, *short circuiting* is one mental device to make this task easier.
It simplifies the circuit by replacing the shorted part with a wire. (A dual operation is *isolating* a suitable part of the circuit.)
In Figure 3.25, I interpret `with ΔV short-circuited` as *without voltage source ΔV*:
The part between \$+V_1\$ and \$+V_2\$ is just two j0.1 in parallel.
This way, establishing the complex power "transmitted to the load" (with \$+S\$ closed) should not be hard given \$+V_1\$ (by waveform, voltage, frequency).
In all likelihood, the *solution (not shown)* goes on to compute what changes when "reintroducing" ΔV.

Answer (score 2):

> How is a short circuit useful at all for measuring the power transmitted through a transformer?

By taking short circuit and open circuit measurements in a circuit, one can find impedances (including mutual impedances). Knowing voltages and impedances, one can find power.

> Doesn't a short circuit imply that the power does NOT reach load?

Yes, a short circuit may have current through it, but not voltage across it. As a result, there is no power dissipated in an ideal short circuit. However, if one measures the current through the short circuit, one may use the found value to calculate the impedance of other parts of the circuit, and the impedance values thus found, may be useful in calculating the power in the circuit with a non-zero load instead of the short circuit.

Comment: (The quote in the question (sort of) mentions *ΔV* shorted, not a short parallel to the load as subsequently assumed there.)

Comment: @greybeard the shorting of ΔV is precisely what I'm asking about. I assume shorting ΔV means opening the switch S (as illustrated in the figure)? Seems like an odd thing to do; seems like you would want S to be closed when measuring power transmitted to the load.